# counter-reset is not working on converting from html to docx by cloud convert while it is taking correct number in UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, cloudconvert

```
body {
  font: smaller sans-serif;
    counter-reset: h1 h2;
 }
 h1:before {
    content: counter(h1) ". ";
      counter-increment: h1;
   }
     h1 {
      counter-reset: h2;
     }
    h2:before {
      content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
      counter-increment: h2;
      }



   <h1>Heading</h1>
   <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
    <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
     <h1>Heading</h1>
     <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
        <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
```

output of docx file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGUux.png)

I am trying to convert from html to docx through cloud convert Api but is is missing list numbers seen in SS, Thanks in advance[UI SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtuw7.png)

Comment: I don't see any JS here - how are you calling the API or are you using the service: https://cloudconvert.com/html-to-docx ? pseudo elements are not in the DOM so I wonder whether that is the problem?

Comment: yes I am using the service  cloudconvert.com/html-to-docx , it is not working as expected the numbers are not showing in docx after converting

Comment: I am using all css within style tag in head and html within body tag, nothing else

Comment: why this html is not getting numbers is docx after converting from cloud converter

Comment: this html not giving no.<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>body {counter-reset: h1 h2 h3;}
  h1:before {content: counter(h1) ". ";
    counter-increment: h1;}
  h1 { counter-reset: h2;}
  h2 {counter-reset: h3;}
  h2:before {content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) " ";counter-increment: h2; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><h1>first heading</h1>
        <h2>second heading</h2>
        <h3>third heading</h3></div>
</body>
</html>